# Uploading data received via email to data warehouse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-warehouse, amazon-ses

I am going to receive csv files of data from a vendor weekly via email, we use Outlook. I want to upload the attachments into our data warehouse, which is Google BigQuery.

In looking for the easiest way to do this I found Amazon's [Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) which looks like it can automatically save the email and attachment to a storage bucket. This would be great... if only it was on Google Cloud Platform.

Is there a GCP equivalent to this? Or if not is there a standard approach to uploading data files received via email to a warehouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what you are looking for is App Engine, which gives you the possibility to listen to incoming emails via Mail API. You can [read and write attachments to GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage), by specifying the bucket while writing in Cloud Storage.

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
```

To process [receiving email messages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api), you associate email addresses with script handlers in your app configuration, then include the handlers in your app's code.

Please, refer to official documentation and read about [quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/), e.g. maximum size of incoming mail messages, including attachments equals to 31.5 MB.